# dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: not working for iPhone 5

Tags: ios5, ios6, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

So in my iPhone 4 device after I pick a image I want the image picker popover to go away. The following code WORKS for iPad 3 on iOS 5, iPad 4 on iOS 6, iPhone 4 on iOS 5 BUT the following code does not work for iPhone 5 on iOS 6. Why is this?

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[self loadImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) {
    if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        // called for iPad
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}
else {
    // called for iPhone
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; <== NOT WORKING
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; <== ALSO NOT WORKING
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're telling the delegate of the image picker (self) to dismiss, not the image picker itself.